# Temporarily slow down mouse by pressing shift key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

sometimes high precision while using mouse is needed, e.g. when resizing windows, cropping images. It would be very convenient to have some sort of **mouse speed modifier key which while pressed down would slow the mouse down**.
I've seen some laptops running Windows having touch pad control panel where you can set various modifier keys for mouse speed, horizontal/vertical/diagonal movement, etc. But I want to achieve this on **Ubuntu 14.10 or higher using external mouse**.

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to have a solution too. Apparently the unity developers are so busy with other stuff (unity 8?) that they cannot address this long lasting and extremely frustrating `1px windows border` issue that almost makes resizing windows impossible. Having a `slow down mouse` key could help get around this.